# RABL: change default date and time format to iso8601

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, iso8601, rabl

I'm using rabl 0.11.6 for my API, and I find myself doing the following over and over again for every date or time object:

```
node :created_at do |article|
  article.created_at.iso8601
end
```

It would save a lot of code duplication, if the format for every date object could be set in one place, so that I just could use the `attributes` method like this

```
attributes :created_at
```

I found an issue on github (https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails/issues/68) where they suggest, overwriting some `Oj.default_options =  { mode: :compat, time_format: :ruby }` in an initializer. But I have no idea how to do a `.iso8601`.

Then I found this one https://gist.github.com/astevens/b80225d96d8889c946ac. But it looks like a hacky monkey patch solution.

And finally I found this issue https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/336 where they overwrite the `as_json` method from `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, also a very monkey-patch solution.

Is there no way to tell RABL what date and time format to use? And if not, what would be the best / least-hacky method to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this so far. Anyone an idea?

Comment: why would you want to do `in_time_zone` in an API? IMHO it's better to represent all datetimes in an API as UTC  -- this way all values are easy to compare

Comment: You're right, UTC would be fine. But the format should be in ISO8601. I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW I fixed this problem in rails 4.2.8, Rabl 0.13.1 and OJ 2.18.5

Add a initializer with the following..

```
Oj.default_options = {:use_as_json => true}
```

Comment: this is now `use_to_json` on the latest OJ

Answer (score 1):

As crazy as it sounds, this fixes it by changing the JSON serializer:

```
bundle add oj
```

Comment: I can confirm this, by just adding the oj gem it uses iso8601 as default.